# GraphStream have an image as a background

Tags: java, graphstream

I am working in my Java project and I am using GraphStream library to visually represent graphs. My question is how to put an image behind a graph? I want an image as a background to my graph.

Answer (score 2):

The method setBackLayerRenderer() is implemented in the class DefaultView, here's what worked for me:

```
Graph graph = new SingleGraph("graph");`
Viewer viewer = graph.display();
DefaultView view = (DefaultView) viewer.getDefaultView();
view.setBackLayerRenderer(new LayerRenderer() {
    @Override
    public void render(Graphics2D graphics2D, GraphicGraph  graphicGraph, double v, int i, int i1, double v1, double v2, double v3, double v4) {
        graphics2D.setColor(Color.green);
        graphics2D.drawString("hello", 10, 30);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved using `LayerRenderer` interface with 
`View.setBackLayerRenderer() / View.setFrontLayerRenderer()` methods. You can find more [here](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation_1.0/#drawing-in-the-graph-viewer).

Comment: But how do I use those methods ? Where do i put the image location ?

Comment: Please check the url, it has quite detailed stuff.

Comment: I still don´t understand how to put an image behind my graph .. How do I use the View.serBackLayerRenderer() method ?